# Calculating a point inside a polygon

Tags: java, algorithm, 3d, geometry

Let's say that we have a 3d polygon that is defined with three points

- x1, y1, z1
- x2, y2, z2
- x3, y3, z3

Then we have a perpendicular to the Z axis ray with position rX, rY.
How can we find out if the ray is hitting the polygon and in what X,Y,Z the collision is happening.

Any code example will be very useful.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: My math is not very good, so I am using an API from the framework that  shoots a ray and returns me the position of the collision, however it is pretty slow because it doesn't allow you to control the subset of polygons to check for collision. I am hoping to find an algorithm for one triangle and after that adapt it for my needs.

Comment: @AntonBanchev - See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm.  You'll need to add your cross-product, dot-product, and sub-vector computations.

Comment: @lreeder This was what I was looking for, add it as a answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For intersection of a vector with a triangle in 3D, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ller%E2%80%93Trumbore_intersection_algorithm.  You'll need to add your own cross-product (CROSS), dot-product (DOT), and sub-vector (SUB) code for the pseudo-code.